# What makes noise heteroscedastic?

Tags: noise, antenna

I work in the field of spectroscopy, for instance NMR and FT-IR.  For both of these instruments, the advice is to process the data to compensate for heteroscedasticity -- noise that increases as the signal increases.  Let's focus on NMR: the receiver in NMR is a small (~5 mm diameter) solenoid-like winding of wire that acts as an antenna to pick up the signal from the decaying nuclear spins.  The response in the antenna is captured by an ADC. The whole experiment occurs in a strong and ideally homogeneous magnetic field.

I'm wondering, in general, how do we know in this situation that the noise will increase when the signal increases?  It might be helpful to have a counter example of some instrument where the noise is constant regardless of the signal size (homoscedastic noise). I know very little about EE, so I'm hoping for a fairly simple explanation.  If the answer is something along the lines of "in the real world things are always heteroscedastic" perhaps someone could include some of the factors that contribute to the noise.

**Update 27 March 2022**

Though it doesn't directly answer the question I posed, I came across a paper with a great deal of information about the sources of noise in NMR.  See [here](https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/19/14/3064).  The same group has a web interface for playing with the calculations, see [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00051144.2022.2052649).

Comment: Are you asking about the actual noise increasing or the noise in the signal measurement?

Comment: Good question. I'm probably asking a bit about both.  I understand any electrical signal will have noise, I don't know if that is intrinsically heteroscedastic or not.  That is certainly going to contribute to the final result that one analyzes.  If all electrical noise is heteroscedastic then I suppose all instrument signals are as a result.  As far as the noise in the actual physical process, maybe that is for a different forum, or maybe it's philosophical (since said noise is ultimately observed via the noisy electrical signal).  That's one reason I'd be interested in a counter example.

Comment: I posted two comments below and, since you mentioned FT-IR, maybe this link is of interest: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/60031/41790 . The model uses three noise sources: light source temperature fluctuations, mirror positioning noise and detector/preamp noise.

Comment: @EdV Thank you, I will study that post and answer.  Good stuff!

Comment: @EdV that's a great post, and it made me think deeper about my own question.  In NMR, the whole system is set in motion by some sort of RF pulse (there are many variations), but I guess this input stimulus, being shaped by electrical components, of course has it's own noise.  I'm going to think a bit more on this, but more and  more I'm thinking the core of my question is "is electrical noise instrinisically heteroscedastic?"

Comment: References 42 to 44 at the link below might be helpful to you. I can send you the papers if you wish. In paper 42, I deliberately made the noise homoscedastic, while in the next two papers, I made the noise linearly heteroscedastic. https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/410372/247352

Comment: @EdV Thank you, yes please send the papers hanson@depauw.edu

Comment: @BryanHanson Voltage noise on a well-designed system (pre-amplifier and amplifier) may very well be uniform regardless of the signal. (A "noise floor" so to speak.) But the signal itself may (especially in anything having to do with physics, pretty much) be an exponential decline in nature after a preceding stimulus. To solve for the slope (tau) of the exponential, the data may be digitized and converted via a logarithm function. To find the tau, more emphasis is needed on earlier data than later data because later data is "mostly noise," by comparison with earlier.

Comment: @jonk What you describe about the signal is close to what happens in an NMR experiment.  The info about noise on well-designed system is helpful.  Thanks for this.

Comment: @BryanHanson I have a book on the design of and mathematics for processing the data from NMR. It's more than a decade old, but I've read it. (With *some* understanding, I believe.) One of the areas I've worked is in observing the exponential decay of energized atomic states in solid matter physics (triplet to singlet state transitions, and the reverse.) I've had to deal with this issue, continually.

Comment: @jonk Can you send the title?  Might be worth a look.  I understand your *some* understanding comment -- ya gotta take in as much as one can but it may be a lot later before *real* understanding sets in...

Comment: @BryanHanson It's [this one](https://www.amazon.com/dp/3527295127/). I did really enjoy it! My wife wanted me to build one of the darned things here at home. Of course, I gave her good reasons why we weren't going to try that. ;) (Yes, I've built some insane stuff in my life -- including a small, water-cooled FAB using a nickel plated quartz chamber and 300 C/second ramp rates. I learned to not do that without evacuation or else dry nitrogen back-fill!!)

Comment: @BryanHanson _"As far as the noise in the actual physical process, maybe that is for a different forum,"_ - some electronic devices and processes do produce heteroscedastic noise, but in NMR the heteroscedasticity is in the biological material. So I agree that this question should be in a different forum.

Comment: The term is very common in financial time series. Stock volatility is heteroskedastic, meaning clusters of different periods (samples) have different volatility (absolute magnitude of mean reversion variance changes with different samples). Making it difficult to manage, statistically. This is because stock volatility is more autocorrelated (positive feedback makes higher volatility follow higher volatility and vice versa - like fear), hence use of ARCH modeling. This type of data is transformed (like log of series) to make it more uniform to process.

Comment: Same phenomena, due to serial correlation in fNIRS samples shown here. "The Noise in Functional Near-Infrared Spectroscopy Is Correlated" https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/journals/neurophotonics/volume-3/issue-1/010401/Commentary-on-the-statistical-properties-of-noise-and-its-implication/10.1117/1.NPh.3.1.010401.full?SSO=1

Comment: @pat A quick look suggests that paper is worth a deeper dive.  The language seems pretty clear.  Thanks for sharing it, and the reminder about financial time series too.

Answer (score 3):

Carriers crossing junctions exhibit SHOT NOISE, proportional to \$\sqrt { 2  q I_B}\$, where \$I_B\$ is the current (number of carriers per time unit) flowing though the junction.

Answer (score 1):

### Added

Thermal Noise sounds like the eddy currents  of wind and water in nature but in electronics it is the same effect of electrons hitting each other called Brownian Motion.  There is White Noise which is equal energy per unit bandwidth such as the "grass baseline" in a Spectrum Analyzer with a fixed BW scanner.  From this we get a 1/2 order integration or square root noise in audio which we cal[l "pink noise" to get -3dB / octave and "brown noise"](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Colors_of_noise) is -6dB/octave like a 1st order low pass filter.  From photon waves and particle currents, across a boundary, we get **[Shot Noise](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Shot_noise). In Op Amps, we call it Popcorn Noise because it sounds like that.** which is just like the random Particle Discharge PD noise in a high voltage dielectric from impurities.  They defined the pseudo-noise-bandwidth in FCC tests used in the Spectrum Analyzers, based on the 8kHz radio bandwidth during WWI, because they used radios to drive around and detect the faint corona sounds of PD noise from leaky high voltage insulators that required cleaning or repairs. **When it was "really" bad continuous external PD noise, it is called "corona"**, and the AM radio channels would all hum from driving under the overhead lines.

- This reminds me of driving to the pure white quartz and Silica sands of Victoria Beach on Lake Winnipeg, as a kid. Driving under the HV power lines would always interfere with **60 Hz harmonic hum on the AM radio**, but these disturbances are "all cleaned up now" with better creepage specs and porcelain or glass bushing insulators so AM is more noise free except when a lightning storm occurs over hundreds of miles away.
- Even engine ignition noise has been eliminated going from copper ignition cables to 50kohm carbon resistor spark cables to reduce the arc current which is not necessary to ignite the air-fuel mixture.  This is similar to the Solar Noise from massive plasma coronal noise the same as Partial Discharge and causes extremly high voltages induced during Solar Maxima, [Carrington Effects](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Carrington_Event) every couple centuries.  One of the Earth's magnetic resonant frequencies modulates the "magnetosphere" with this stream of solar noise ( and [Schumann Resonance](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Schumann_resonances)) to cause power lines to arc and blowout Satellite front-ends, if not protected from this extreme Gamma-wave interference.

Averaging reduces thermal noise by the number of samples \$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{ N}}\$ but only if it is random. This is similar to brown noise conversion or Integration or  1st order low pass filtering (LPF) in a bin or time fixed interval.

I am not familiar with the use of the term [heteroscedastic](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Heteroscedasticity) but that certain describes electronic noise from many sources.   We are aware of many sources of noise that increase such as [thermal noise](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Colors_of_noise) increases with temperature and Partial Discharge Noise increases with voltage getting closer to the breakdown voltage. We also know that Zener diode noise current increases with current due to temp. rise but increase with low current from a higher resistance* to convert low currents into a larger voltage.  We also know carbon (C) resistors make more thermal noise than plastic **metal film (MF) resistors**, which are preferred these days for lowest cost, low noise and accuracy.

to answer @tobalt 's comment * I believe, more current causes heat and which causes more noise, but at the same time, demands a much smaller resistor to sense the current, so we use the lowest current to measure or create noise in a Zener and thus achieve the highest  voltage gain from R (V=IR).

[Then we have burst noise from some EMI transient created by electromagnetic crosstalk.](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Burst_noise)  **It is also called random telegraph noise (RTN), popcorn noise, impulse noise, bi-stable noise.**

Another type of noise, sometimes called **aliasing noise**, like the difference frequency sounds when two people hum at the same frequency. The lack of this difference frequency noise can cause errors in counters when measuring frequencies of the same low noise as the internal ovenized-crystal oscillator in precision frequency counters. Because of this low noise the internal 10 MHZ OCXO has insufficient dithering or uncertainty to measure accurately and there is no averaging of ...999.999 ...000.000 to get the 12 or more digits of frequency accuracy and so some random noise must be added to measure it. This low phase noise is inherent with SC-cut crystals and are 6 orders of magnitude less noise than the typical standard SC-cut crystals used everywhere in computers, phones, and radios.  (They are also 4 orders of magnitude more expensive), but are most stable when kept in an oven at a constant temperature around 85'C.

*Please edit, if you find a minor error. I am sure I forgot something and there **must be** more examples of hetero noise.*

Comment: It is a strange word for sure.  It's fairly common term in the statistics world, a bit in signal processing  and economics (I searched those SO forums before deciding to ask here).  Apparently in Greek skedasis = scattering.

Comment: Do these 3 examples correlate with your spectroscopy experience?    Does this imply there is an optimum level for SNR? or is it that it triggers noise from activation potentials or can be destructive interference.

Comment: NMR produces a decaying sine wave.  I assume this shows up in the detector antenna and everything electrical downstream pretty much unchanged, so a voltage that is decaying.  If that voltage was 100 mv would EE theory expect it to be noisier than a voltage that was 10 mv?  I'm making up these voltages for discussion.

Comment: The level alone cannot differentiate between signal and noise

Comment: but a low phase noise single decaying frequency does not suggest much noise. Just an underdamped resonance.

Comment: The (ideal) NMR signal is a sum of individual resonance frequencies collected over a time domain, and eventually FT'd to give a frequency display to the end user.  I suppose theoretically there is no noise (though there are artifacts, these are not noise).  So maybe all noise comes only from the detector system?  The end user sees signals over a baseline that is noisy.  Almost always signal averaging is used to reduce that noise.  I guess that noise is all electrical (?).

Comment: If that is the case, we would expect the noise is constant and SNR increases with signal level which makes it homoscedastic (?)

Comment: Heteroscedastic means different scattering while homoscedastic means same scattering, where scattering means variance in the noise afflicting the measurements. Suppose you are doing photon counting or mass spectroscopy. Then Poisson statistics is relevant, so the mean equals the variance. On the other hand, if you are doing an optical absorbance measurement, and the photodetector and preamp combo contributes the dominant noise, then the noise is independent of the signal, hence homoscedastic. It is often assumed that measurement noises are homoscedastic, because this greatly simplifies

Comment: the analysis and processing. In reality, heteroscedastic noises are common and then a giant can of worms is opened: there are many possible ways the noise might functionally depend on the signal and even if theory provides guidance, which is often not the case, then you have to deal with the noise. For example, if you want to do linear regression, then heteroscedastic noise afflicting the measurements means weighted least squares is necessary. But then you need the true variances, which you almost never have. These two comments are far too little to do justice to your question!

Comment: Thank you @EdV your comments are helpful! Based on Tony Stewart's comment about signal averagging, I'm wondering if a single scan is essentially heteroscedastic but the signal averaging offsets that. I'm going to have to think about this a bit more...

Comment: One of my colleagues used to average 10000 FT-NMR spectra, change conditions slightly, average another 10000 spectra, then subtract to get what they were looking for. This certainly helped the SNR, but heteroscedasticity depends on the signal, so I do not think it reduces the heteroscedasticity.

Comment: Averaging removes random noise. Or rather it removes noise that is not coherent with the signal. It improves the signal to noise ratio. But the fundamental assumption of averaging is that the signal of interest does not change from trial to trial.

Comment: *"We also know that Zener diode noise increases with current."* In which context is that so ? For Zener-based shunt references, the noise actually decreases the more current flows through the Zener diode, according to some datasheets, e.g. LTZ1000 IIRC

Answer (score 1):

> For both of these instruments, the advice is to process the data to compensate for heteroscedasticity -- noise that increases as the signal increases.

Heteroscedasticity is a common phenomenon any time you amplify a noisy signal: the relative signal-to-noise ratio remains largely the same, so the *absolute* amplitude of noise at the output is larger the larger the signal is.

In case of NMR, the noise comes from the underlying physical process, and from the various uncertainties we inject into it through the stimulus we apply. The signal level in the resulting measurement is a measure of inherent amplification applied to the process's parameter being measured. The process is noisy, you amplify its output by using a more sensitive sensing setup, and if the noise of the process was larger than the noise floor of your measuring system, then you'll observe an increase in the noise that's proportional to the signal amplitude.

The phenomenon may look out-of-place, since in many cases the noise floor of the measuring device is the limiting factor, e.g. in low voltage preamplifier systems, and the noise inherent in the physics of the measured process is lower. But whenever heteroscedasticity is observed in spite of measuring a larger signal without changing the noise level of the measuring device, then we know that the noise comes from the signal source itself - we just amplified it more, along with the rest of the signal.

There's way more to NMR noise shaping that I know next to nothing about, but heteroscedasticity is a common phenomenon that always points to the same culprit: the actual physical system that we measure, and that we potentially inject noise/uncertainty into.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is another shot at answering. In NMR, we have two distinct situations. If we have a lot of sample, then the sample noise becomes important and will dominate over the equipment, else it is only the noise generated in the equipment that is dominant. So, in the prior case, the signal and the noise depend on the sample, and so increase together. In the latter, the noise will remain independent of the amount of sample.

Frankly, I have never encountered the terminology "heteroscedastic", at least not among NMR people.

Comment: Please Tell us more about microscale NMR hardware. I am trying to generate 4 Tesla EM muscular skeletal waves at 400Hz, air cooled. My former colleague helped invent the 7T portable non-magnetic MRI at NRC.